# FMX: TForm.Show and TForm.ShowModal sometimes results in form shown underneath main form

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

This is an issue that happens intermittently. A secondary form is shown using Show or ShowModal, it appears on top for a fraction of a second but then disappears behind the main form. If the window is not modal then the solution is just to repeat the action again to show the form or unmaximise the main form if needed, and move it to reveal the other form. However, if the form is modal then there's no way out. The application is halted until the modal window is closed and there's no way to close it with it hidden behind the main form and no way to move the main form. The application has to be closed from Task Manager (not good).

I'm using Delphi 10.4. Has anyone else experienced this issue? Has it been reported and does anyone have a solution?

Comment: "there's no way out": You just need to press Alt+Space, the underlined character in "Move", and then use the arrow keys to bring the form into visibility. Or, if you have more than one monitor, Win+Shift+Left/Right will work. (And to close it: Alt+F4 or Alt+Space followed by the underlined character in "Close" will do that.)

Comment: OK, there may be an expert way out but I'm sure you can appreciate that most users won't know this or at the very least will find it annoying whenever it happens. I'd like to avoid it happening in the first place.

Comment: Of course. This behaviour must not happen in any app.

Comment: Intermittently? If you have `FormStyle.StayOnTop` on the main form it does stay on top, also on top of `ShowModal` forms. But that is not intermittent. Anyway, maybe the `StayOnTop` is the reason? I'm not aware of any other possible reason. (warn. speculation) Unless you do something in the event handler, which calls up the secondary window, that brings focus back to the main form.

Comment: @XylemFlow that's no "expert way" - unplug your mouse and then see how far you come. If the keyboard is not enough you encountered bad software. And you learn how far you can go with just the keyboard (or even become much faster because of all the shortcuts). I literally see people not even using the TAB key but instead the mouse.

Comment: I think a main form should almost never be `fsStayOnTop`. "you have no means to get to the modal window": not strictly true.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Maybe not strictly true on all platforms that FMX supports. I guess you are thinking about some keyboard shortcuts on Windows only?

Comment: @TomBrunberg: Yes. When the modal form is focused (even if it is hidden behind the main form), you just need to press Alt+Space, the underlined character in "Move", and then use the arrow keys to bring the form into visibility. Or, if you have more than one monitor, Win+Shift+Left/Right will work. (And to close it: Alt+F4 or Alt+Space followed by the underlined character in "Close" will do that.) Although I am mainly nitpicking, the difference might be rather important if you have important unsaved data in the app.

Comment: My main form style is fsNormal, not fsStayOnTop. If that were the case I'd expect to see the issue every time. That is not the issue.

Comment: @AmigoJack, I've been a Windows developer for 20 years and still don't know many of the windows shortcuts. I've just never needed them. My application is designed to be used by children as young as 5 so I don't think that unplugging the mouse and seeing how far they get is the best solution here.